# jQuery Ajax call when using PHP Xdebug hangs web app

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xdebug

When using php Xdebug and sending the ajax call below it hangs and never finishes. But if I don't use Xdebug it works fine.

Also, if I use `<form action="/controllers/scannerController.php" method="post">` to send the post it works. Has anyone encountered this problem before or can provide a solution?

```
function submitScannedText(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../controllers/scannerController.php',
        data: {text: $("#scannerEntry").val() },
            });
}
```

Comment: This may depend on your Xdebug client (editor/IDE that you are using to debug your PHP code). For example: you may already have one debug session and your IDE/editor does not support more than one active session. Or .. it stopped on breakpoint and awaits your commands (in the IDE/editor). Enable and collect Xdebug log and see what it will say -- it will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',` below `type: "POST",` please ?

Ajax will maybe now send it the same way as your `<form action="/controllers/scannerController.php" method="post">` do and PHP can handle it the same way. Please let me know if it worked :)

Also if it's not working you should also add  `processData : false,`.

Comment: Thanks; it was actually a race condition of sorts, because I was sending the POST data too soon, perhaps while the page was not yet fully loaded. When I waited a second before sending the data, it didn't hang. But your answer nonetheless motivated me to investigate more and get the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Philip and nice to know you fixed it :) Say safe and have a nice end of the year.